# Compiling SASS in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, sass, phamlp

I'm looking to implement SASS (http://sass-lang.org) into my CakePHP app. But instead of compiling it using the command line via Ruby, I want to make it so that it automatically converts the SASS files into CSS when the app is in debug mode.

I have done this in the past with LESS. Has anyone done anything like this for SASS in CakePHP?

An example of how I see it working (based on how my LESS implementation worked):

```
if (Configure::read('debug') > 0)
{
    // import sass compiler
    App::import('Vendor', 'vendorName');

    $sass_directory = ROOT . DS . APP_DIR . DS . 'webroot' . DS . 'sass' . DS;

    $css_directory = ROOT . DS . APP_DIR . DS . 'webroot' . DS . 'css' . DS;

    vendorName::toCss($sass_directory, $css_directory);
}
```

So it would read all the files in the SASS directory and then compile it into CSS and put it in the CSS directory.

According to the PHamlP docs: https://code.google.com/p/phamlp/wiki/SassOptions this plugin can convert and move entire directories. **Anyone able to confirm that this does what I think?**

I've tested it on a standalone PHP file:

```
require_once('Vendor/PHamlP_3.2/sass/SassParser.php');

$sass = new SassParser(array('style'=>'nested','template_location'=>'./sass','css_location'=>'./css'));

$css = $sass->toCss('./sass/master.scss');

echo $css;
```

Which works... But why do I bother declaring the SASS location and CSS location in the options if I then have to tell it where the SASS file lives (and can only choose one) and then it doesn't actually do anything with the CSS file...

Can someone provide some ideas of how I could make it automatically take the SASS files from the template_directory and then save it in the CSS directory compiled?

I noticed that PHamlP has a CakePHP download: https://code.google.com/p/phamlp/downloads/list but it's old and seems to want to run actual referenced SASS files through the Parser rather than just compile them and reference the created CSS files. Unless I'm wrong? And the CakePHP version does only reference the CSS files builds them using the SASS files.

**Update:** I've tried PHamlP and it only works with .sass and not .scss! Also seems to be able to only run individual files through the filter rather than convert an entire folder e.g. say I was using Compass and wanted to compile it all into one file etc..

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the time to write a complete answer (with code example etc...) right now but you might want to have a look at [scssphp](http://leafo.net/scssphp/) it seems to have the ability to take a whole directory and process it, it seems also able to recompile only changed file.

As a side note, if it's the auto-recompilation while in dev mode you're looking for, SASS has a `--watch` parameter to auto recompile SCSS files and [compass](http://compass-style.org/) has a `watch` command that will do the same on top of bringing a whole lot of mixins you can use in your SCSS.